# "predicted at" vs "predicted for"

Tags: prepositions

If you are trying to say that a bus will arrive some time in the future do you use "predicted at 2pm" or "predicted for 2pm"?

Comment: *Predicted* simply isn't the right word in this context. You could use ***expected at*** or ***scheduled for***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I haven't thought of that but _expected_ sounds much better than _predicted_ in this context. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the arrival is planned, I would say the bus is *scheduled for 2 PM*.  "Predicted" connotes an element of uncertainty (i.e. "we predicted it will arrive at 2 PM, but we might be wrong").

Comment: Kevin, I'm writing an app that deals with public transportation services and in addition to the regular schedule some providers publish predictions too (they track vehicles with a GPS and estimate how off they will be from the posted schedule). I can only fit 2 or 3 words on the app to show this info that's why I chose "predicted at/for". Do you think it's proper to say "predicted at 2pm"?

Comment: Use "predicted *at*"

Comment: @Julian - wouldn't you want to express this as predicted *to arrive at...0420*, rather than merely *predicted at...0420*?

Comment: @LittleEva in an ideal case I would, except that I have very little real estate in which to show this info so I unfortunately have to be brief.